# How to see content of built-in android.jar

Tags: android, android-resources

Is there anyway to see res/drawable/... files?
when I click on .png files it says: "System editor can only open file base resources"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway to see res/drawable/... files?

Find them in your Android SDK directory, then open them in your favorite image editing program. You can find them in `$SDK/platforms/$API/data/res/`, where `$SDK` is wherever you installed your Android SDK and `$API` is a directory for a particular API level (e.g., `android-19` for API Level 19).

Note that `android.jar` is a JAR file and does not contain Android-style resources.